# Relation between product and user in opencart?

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, opencart2.x

How to identify which product added by which user(not customers) in opencart? any table or data in database related to user and product?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: if you are a technical person than you will get your answer from here: http://wiki.opencarthelp.com/lib/exe/detail.php?id=databse_schema&media=database_schema_oc1541_product.png

Comment: @devpro +1, nice link

Answer (score 0):

There is no such relation. But you can create a field in `oc_products` table named as `add_by_user_id` and can insert the id using session by `$this->user->getId()`.